OnActorPreSpawnInitialization delegate broadcast is completely ignored after deployment on Android
Im running UE 5.3
I’ve created game instance subsystem C++ class which adds specific logic to be run before every spawned actor is initialized. Please see piece of code below. It works good when I run my game in PIE mode in Unreal Engine on PC. But when I deploy it on my Android, game never goes inside of Lambda which I added to OnActorPreSpawnInitialization. Any help why it is ignored would be really appreciated.
void UMyGameInstanceSubsystem::Initialize(FSubsystemCollectionBase& Collection)
{
    auto ActorSpawnLambda = FOnActorSpawned::FDelegate::CreateLambda([this](AActor* InActor)
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemplateCBGameInstanceSubsystem, Warning, TEXT("Run lambda Starting point"));
            if (AChaosCachePlayer* CCP = Cast<AChaosCachePlayer>(InActor))
            {
                if (ChaosCacheCollection_Temp)
                {
                    UE_LOG(LogTemplateCBGameInstanceSubsystem, Warning, TEXT("Run lambda from class UMyGameInstanceSubsystem "));
                    PostSpawnChaosCachePlayer(CCP, ChaosCacheCollection_Temp);
                    ChaosCacheCollection_Temp = NULL;
                }
            }
        });
    UE_LOG(LogTemplateCBGameInstanceSubsystem, Warning, TEXT("GameInstance subsystem is Initialized"));
    GetWorld()->AddOnActorPreSpawnInitialization(ActorSpawnLambda);
}


GameInstanse subsystem is loading earlier than GameMode for Android. Delegate can be added in e.g. GameMode constructor to overcome this issue.
